# Abaqus Python get Stresses at each nodes and save in text file

Tags: python, text, abaqus

I m trying to extract stresses at each nodes or each integration points. 
I can get stresses but i have nothing to know where it is situated the values.
How can i add the node number or node coordinate? Below it is my code to extract just all stresses components

```
from odbAccess import *
import numpy as np

odb = openOdb(path='C:/Users/Solal/Job-1.odb')

lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]


location = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['COORD']
stress=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['S']  
sortie = open('Resu_PE_maillage.txt', 'w')
sortie.write('\t S11 \t\t S22 \t\t S33 \t\t  S12 \t\t S23 \t\t S13 \n')


for S in stress.values:
    sortie.write('%.10e\t\t %.10e\t\t %.10e\t\t %.10e\t\t %.10e\t\t %.10e\n' % (S.data[0], S.data[1], S.data[2], S.data[3], S.data[4], S.data[5]))

sortie.close()
```

Comment: Try using prettyPrint to look at all the things in S. You can get the label from S.

Answer (score 1):

1. open odb
2. select step and frame number in assembly
3. loop on node by number-index:

   ```
   for i in range (len(....nodes)):

       N=....nodes[i]
   ```
4. find stress for each node
5. write i and stress to your text file